# How to show orientation axis in Pymol

Tags: proteins, vmd, structural-biology, pdb, pymol

Is there a way  to show the orientation axis in Pymol?

It's something like this in VMD. I much prefer Pymol rendering.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no built in way to display the coordinate vectors. Fortunately, on the PyMOLWiki I was able to find [a page with a number of scripts you can use to do this](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Axes).

Comment: Could you add one of the solutions that work?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I agree that adding it would improve my answer but I’m a little bit spooked by the licensing requirement

Comment: At the end of that page is written: _Content is available under GNU Free Documentation License 1.2 unless otherwise noted_, so, I think that sharing here will be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

The supplied answer is correct, but is script and I (a passerby, not OP or responder) wanted a copypaste in the GUI. To make the code okay for copy pasting (i.e. no multilines):

```py
from pymol.cgo import CYLINDER, cyl_text
from pymol.vfont import plain

obj = [CYLINDER, 0., 0., 0., 10., 0., 0., 0.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0., CYLINDER, 0., 0., 0., 0., 10., 0., 0.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0., 1.0, 0.,CYLINDER, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 10., 0.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0., 0.0, 1.0,]

cyl_text(obj,plain,[-5.,-5.,-1],'Origin',0.20,axes=[[3,0,0],[0,3,0],[0,0,3]])
cyl_text(obj,plain,[10.,0.,0.],'X',0.20,axes=[[3,0,0],[0,3,0],[0,0,3]])
cyl_text(obj,plain,[0.,10.,0.],'Y',0.20,axes=[[3,0,0],[0,3,0],[0,0,3]])

cmd.load_cgo(obj,'axes')
```

The change away from star import is because it is evil unless one knows what there is on the `__all__` variable of that module. Nothing to do with PyMOL GUI faux-terminal.